# Does Hyper-V support nested virtualization on AMD CPUs with AMD-V?

Tags: windows, virtualization, hyper-v, windows-10

Some [article published on 2015](https://www.petri.com/windows-10-build-10565-adds-nested-hyper-v) stated that Windows 10 preview versions weren't supporting nested virtualization on AMD-V AMD CPUs.

Now I've tried to enable nested virtualization on my up-to-date Windows 10 and once I try to run a Windows 10 Hyper-V VM an error message is thrown stating that nested virtualization isn't supported on this platform.

My CPU is an AMD Athlon II X3 with AMD-V.

Any insights on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [You need] An Intel processor with VT-x and EPT technology.

So no, it's not (yet?) supported on AMD CPUs.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/nested-virtualization

Comment: It will be on the future, but not sure exactly when. I use ESXI anyway.